# Wildcard * in CSS for specific classes

Tags: html, css

I have the `divs` below that I'm styling with `.thumb` and unique identifiers `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4`, `t5`, `t6`, `t7`, etc.

```
<div class="thumb t1">   thumb 1   </div>
<div class="thumb t2">   thumb 2   </div>
<div class="thumb t3">   thumb 3   </div>
<div class="thumb t4">   thumb 4   </div>
<div class="thumb t5">   thumb 5   </div>
<div class="thumb t6">   thumb 6   </div>
<div class="thumb t7">   thumb 7   </div>
```

`.t(x)` classes can get values from `1` up to `1000` eg. `t1`, `t2`, `t3`....`t1000`

Is there any way using `CSS` wildcard `*` to add a rule only in `elements` that have `classes` from `t5` and up ?

I could use for example

```
.t5, .t6, .t6,.t7,.t8, ..., .t1000 {
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

But it's very inconvenience to write all those numbers up to `t1000`!

Comment: No it isn't duplicated question. The link u provided above adds the wildcard for all elements that have the s(x) identifier. If you read carefully my question you will notice that i need to add the wild card only for elements that have the class t5 and up and on all of them !

Comment: I am adding 5 duplicates, but you need to refresh to see them all

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif This code worked for me: 

.thumb[class^="t"]:nth-child(n+5) {
position:absolute!important;
 }

Comment: In these cases a dummy div will do the job.  `<div class="wrapthumbs"> put here all your divs </div>` and then use css `.wrapthumbs .thumb { your css of the divs }`